# find a hash value which points to another hash value

Tags: perl

I have an array of hash `$ITEM1` as following, couple of the hash value is a pointer `'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => $ITEM1->[0]{'isSNS'}` point back to `'isSNS' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )`.

How do I print out the value for `'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping'`?

```
my $ITEM1 = [
          {
            'trackingSince' => 1460340,
            'rootCategory' => 172282,
            'itemWidth' => 178,
            'binding' => 'Personal Computers',
            'availabilityAmazon' => 2,
            'isSNS' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
            'launchpad' => $ITEM1->[0]{'isSNS'},
            'format' => undef,
            'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => $ITEM1->[0]{'isSNS'}
          }
        ];
```

Comment: That value _is_ the value with the key `isSNS` (which is an object) -- because that's what it will be evaluated to when it is queried; so you say `$ITEM1->[0]{isEligi...}` and you'll get that object.  Is that what you are asking, or something else...?

Comment: The "value" for a key allows for an expression that is evaluated in a scalar context, returning a scalar, and then that's the value. In this case it happens to yield another element of this very hash, the value for `isSNS` key.

Comment: Where does this come from, this (`$ITEM1`) arrayref?

Comment: this ($ITEM1)  come from a api return

Comment: Ah, there -- is there any documentation for that API?  I somehow suspect that there may be better ways to do what you need, other than digging in this complex data structure.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the output of something such as Data::Dumper, but modified somehow. As you have it written because it needs to reference itself to make itself.

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;

my $value = bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
my $ITEM1 = [
          {
            'trackingSince' => 1460340,
            'rootCategory' => 172282,
            'itemWidth' => 178,
            'binding' => 'Personal Computers',
            'availabilityAmazon' => 2,
            'isSNS' => $value,
            'launchpad' => $value,
            'format' => undef,
            'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => $value,
          }
        ];

use Data::Dumper;

say Dumper( $ITEM1 );
```

This produces:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'launchpad' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
            'format' => undef,
            'availabilityAmazon' => 2,
            'itemWidth' => 178,
            'trackingSince' => 1460340,
            'isSNS' => $VAR1->[0]{'launchpad'},
            'binding' => 'Personal Computers',
            'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => $VAR1->[0]{'launchpad'},
            'rootCategory' => 172282
          }
        ];
```

But, this isn't something that you can eval back into Perl because it's self-referential. The variable doesn't even exist yet if you put a `my` in front of it. Data::Dumper resists re-dumping things it has already seen so it refers back to them. Consider, for instance, having to repeatedly dump the same DateTime object: it can really slow down the process and explode the output size.

You can tell Data::Dumper to not do this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
say Dumper( $ITEM1 );
```

Now it doesn't make those references:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'availabilityAmazon' => 2,
            'trackingSince' => 1460340,
            'isSNS' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
            'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
            'itemWidth' => 178,
            'launchpad' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
            'binding' => 'Personal Computers',
            'format' => undef,
            'rootCategory' => 172282
          }
        ];
```

But, you should probably be using something different upstream so you aren't playing with Data::Dumper. There are [various security problems](https://www.masteringperl.org/2014/10/the-datadumper-stack-smash-fixed/) with Perl modules that recreate objects.

Answer (score 3):

When dumping something obtained from a JSON deserializer, I like to use

```perl
print(Data::Dumper->Dump(
   [ $mod->true, $mod->false, $data ],
   [qw( $true $false $data )],
));
```

```
$true = bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
$false = bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
$data = [
          {
            'availabilityAmazon' => 2,
            'isSNS' => $false,
            'launchpad' => $false,
            'rootCategory' => 172282,
            'format' => undef,
            'itemWidth' => 178,
            'isEligibleForSuperSaverShipping' => $false,
            'binding' => 'Personal Computers',
            'trackingSince' => 1460340
          }
        ];
```

It's more readable that way.

This works for Cpanel::JSON::XS, JSON::XS, JSON::PP and JSON.